# Change a separator from dot to comma for a particular column while BCP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MS-SQL BCP query which i am using to export data in excel file and for a particular column i want to have a separator as comma instead of dot.

Below is my BCP query and i want to have `AMOUNT` field to be extracted with a Comma separator and currently it is set to dot, eg actual output `AMOUNT=45.88` expected `AMOUNT=45,88`

```
SELECT      @Command = 'bcp "SELECT QUANTITY,AMOUNT FROM "' +  @dbname + '".dbo.MY_TABLE " queryout ' + @EXTRACT_DETAILS + ' -S' + @@servername + ' -T -c -C "" '
EXEC @ReturnValue=master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

I don't want to modify my table and just want to change the extract separator.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, using `REPLACE`

```
SELECT      @Command = 'bcp "SELECT QUANTITY,
REPLACE(AMOUNT,''.'','','') AS AMOUNT FROM "' +  @dbname + '".dbo.MY_TABLE " queryout ' + 
@EXTRACT_DETAILS + ' -S' + @@servername + ' -T -c -C "" '
EXEC @ReturnValue=master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Here is the change:

`REPLACE(AMOUNT,''.'','','')`

Comment: Thanksa Lot Kay..

This is what i was looking for -

Ive used below and it worked :-)

cast (AMOUNT as decimal(18,2) ),''.'','','')